# how to sort text value word by word

Tags: r, sorting, text

In my problem, each value of a vector is a text composed of multiple words. I try to sort word by word the text. I don't care to sort the vector. 
e.g.

```
vect <- c("tim is a man", "sam was a studend", "my young daughter")
```

how to get vect arranged like this :

```
"a is man tim"
"a sam student was"
"daughter my young"
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the string into substring and then do the `sort`

```
sapply(strsplit(vect, "\\s+"), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=' '))
#[1] "a is man tim"      "a sam studend was" "daughter my young"
```

Comment: that's perfect ! thank you very much for your very quick and true answer